# Are there known situations where this weaker form of the section conjecture holds?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry

Let $k$ be a number field. The section conjecture predicts that for a (smooth geometrically connected) hyperbolic curve over $k$, the profinite Kummer map $\kappa :X(k) \rightarrow \mathscr{J}_{\pi_1(X/k)}$ is a bijection. In our case this map is injective, and we have the following commutative diagram

$$\begin{matrix} X(k) & \hookrightarrow & X(\mathbb{A}_k)_\bullet^{\mathrm{f-desc}} & 
\hookrightarrow & X(\mathbb{A}_k)_\bullet^{\mathrm{Br}}\\
\stackrel\kappa{}{\Big\downarrow} && \stackrel\kappa{}\Big\downarrow && \stackrel\kappa{}\Big\downarrow \\
\mathscr{J}_{\pi_1(X/k)} & \twoheadrightarrow & \mathscr{J}_{\pi_1(X/k)}(\mathbb{A}_k)^{\mathrm{f-desc}} & \hookrightarrow & \mathscr{J}_{\pi_1(X/k)}(\mathbb{A}_k)^{\mathrm{Br}} \end{matrix}$$

where the vertical arrows are all injections and the surjectivity of the first map in the second row is the so-called *strong approximation* result for sections, see Theorem 144 of the book *Rational points and the arithmetic of fundamental groups* by Jacob Stix.

Of course when $X$ is a hyperbolic curve of genus at least $2$ and **if** the section conjecture holds for $X$, then $$X(\mathbb{A}_k)_\bullet^{\mathrm{f-desc}} \rightarrow \mathscr{J}_{\pi_1(X/k)}(\mathbb{A}_k)^{\mathrm{f-desc}}$$ is a bijection and it follows that $X(k) = X(\mathbb{A}_k)_\bullet^{\mathrm{f-desc}}$ is an equality of finite sets. By keeping the hypotheses on $X$, are there known examples where, **without** assuming the section conjecture, the weaker equality $$X(\mathbb{A}_k)_\bullet^{\mathrm{f-desc}} = \mathscr{J}_{\pi_1(X/k)}(\mathbb{A}_k)^{\mathrm{f-desc}}$$ holds?